# Sql/MyBatis, Query column values generated by previous case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis

I'm currently working on a MyBatis mapper.
I have a case statement like below

Case(
When colname is null
Then 'Y'
Else 'N'
End
) as newValue

My question is,
Is it possible to evaluate the 'Y' 'N' within this column later on within a mybatis If test?

I have all other conditions working apart from this one.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about MyBatis, but `colname = null` will never be true. That should be `colname is null`.

Comment: Thank you William. You are right, it was attempt at sudo code. I'll edit it now. Do you know if it is possible to query the alias newValue for the 'Y' ' N' values created by the case statement?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by "query the alias". The `case` statement is still incorrect though - you need to get rid of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to compute the new value before the execution of the SQL statement based on parameters (in your app), or as a part of the SQL statement (in the database engine).

**In your app**

If your value is evaluated before the execution of the SQL based on parameters you can use `<bind>`. For example:

```
<select ...>
  <bind name="newValue" value="colname == null ? 'Y' : 'N'" />
  select * from t where status = #{newValue}
</select>
```

**In the database engine**

You can use a table expression for this. For example:

```
<select ...>
  select *,
    concat('Status is: ', newValue) as long_status
  from (
    select t.*,
      case when colname is null then 'Y' else 'N' end as newValue
    from t
  ) x
</select>
```

**Back from the database engine**

You could compute this in the engine and then receive it back using MyBatis. That's as simple as retrieving a new column from the table, that's actually an SQL expression.